# How to fix this simple code involving main?

Tags: python

```
def execute():
    url_test = "21{}"
    for i in{count}:
        url = url_test.format(i)

def main():
    count = 20000001
    while True:
        count += 1
        print(count)
        if execute():
            break

main()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/Guest/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/1.py", line 15, in <module>

    main()

  File "C:/Users/Guest/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/1.py", line 12, in main

    if execute():

  File "C:/Users/Guest/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/1.py", line 3, in execute

    for i in{count}:

NameError: name 'count' is not defined
```

How do i define count without messing the execute?

Comment: Pass it as a parameter e.g. `if execute(count)`?

Comment: Or you can declare `count` as global variable

Comment: @Yeheshuah, now I have to go and check your answers to see if there's similarly bad advice in them :-)  <-- note the smiley, just kidding (about the checking, I'm serious about the advice being bad).

Comment: Yeah it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @paxdiablo, I didn't want to provide the best advice, cuz you already did it ;) Just added one possible way. Good advice or bad it's different talking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good programming practice indicates that you should minimise coupling between different components<sup>(1)</sup> as much as possible. In this case, that means using parameters to pass information, such as with:

```
def execute(count):
    url_test = "21{}"
    for i in{count}:
        url = url_test.format(i)
    return False

def main():
    count = 20000001
    while True:
        count += 1
        print(count)
        if execute(count):
            break

main()
```

---

As an aside, I'm not sure I fully understand what this segment of your code is *meant* to be doing:

```
for i in {count}:
    url = url_test.format(i)
```

Since `{count}` is a one-element set containing `count`, it's no different to just doing (without the `for` loop):

```
url = url_test.format(count)
```

You may want to rethink either how you're doing this, or what you're *trying* to do.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> What I mean by that is that there should be limited information flow. The general practice is "maximum coherence, minimum coupling", meaning that things that belong together should *be* together, while things that don't should be well isolated from each other.

For calling functions, it should be parameters passed in and values returned, *not* attempting global variable access or access to variables created in another function. You can *do* that, by putting `global count` at the top of `man()`, making it global, but it's actually not a good idea since it allows any function access to it, breaking encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def execute(count):
    url_test = "21{}"
    for i in {count}:
        url = url_test.format(i)
    return False

def main():
    count = 20000001
    while True:
        count += 1
        print(count)
        if execute(count):
            break

main()
```

Comment: You should be aware that `{count}` and `range(0, count)` are *vastly* different beasts.

Comment: @paxdiablo can you explain the difference, please

Comment: The expression `{count}` is a set containing the single item `count`, while `range(0, count)` is an iterable which will give you the values `0..count-1` inclusive if you iterate over it. Hence, if you assign with `count = 5`, the former will run the loop body once, the latter five times. And, since the former is a set, you'll get a single value even for `{count, count, count}`.